# ret&corners are always False&None

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

ret&corners are always False&None.I wrote img.py

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
from PIL import Image

# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

images = Image.open('cosme.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(images),cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Find the chess board corners
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (7,6),None)
print(ret)
print(corners)

# If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
if ret == True:
   objpoints.append(objp)

   corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
   imgpoints.append(corners2)

   # Draw and display the corners
   img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (7,6), corners2,ret)
   cv2.imshow('img',img)
   cv2.waitKey(0)
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Always ret is False,so image is not shown.print(ret) shows False and print(corners) shows None ,so always program does not go into if statement.
I really cannot understand why ret are always False because gray has normal value.I think (7,6) causes this error but I cannot know what causes this error.What is wrong in my codes?How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted the image itself -  it should have a calibration checkerboard with inner corner dimensions of 7,6 visible in it - if the corners aren't found, then the return value is False and the list of corners will be None